# Is Leviticus 19:16 a negative commandment?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, mitzvah, sin, parashas-kedoshim

I heard that the *posuk* *"You shall not stand over the blood of your friend – I am Hashem"* (Vayikra [19:16](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9920#v=16)) is a לאו (negative commandment). Is that true?

> לא תעמד על דם רעך אני יקוק

Comment: This is a case where avoiding a לאו requires action.

Answer (score 8):

It is a prohibition not to stand by as another Jew is in any kind of danger, be it physical or financial.

ALL of the Monei Hamitzvos include it. See Behag 93, Saadia Gaon 61, [Rambam 297](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/0002.htm), [Semag 165](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22640&st=&pgnum=379&hilite=), Ramban 293, [Chinuch 237](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01644_part_237.html), Semak 79, etc.

Comment: I've seen this extended to spiritual danger, too, though I don't recall a source offhand. (Though R' Elchanan Wasserman wrote a letter to the Tz'irei Yisrael youth group in 1939 indicating that Torah study provides protection from physical harm and therefore involves לא תעמוד).

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to, though the Chafetz Chaim (Chomas Hadas 1:3) brings similar Mitzvos for spiritual dangers, including  כִּי תִפְגַּע שׁוֹר אֹיִבְךָ, אוֹ חֲמֹרוֹ--תֹּעֶה:  הָשֵׁב תְּשִׁיבֶנּוּ, לוֹ. and לֹא-תִרְאֶה אֶת-שׁוֹר אָחִיךָ אוֹ אֶת-שֵׂיוֹ, נִדָּחִים, וְהִתְעַלַּמְתָּ, מֵהֶם:  הָשֵׁב תְּשִׁיבֵם, לְאָחִיךָ.

Comment: @Zvi I think the Chafetz Chaim was more homiletic than an actual Mitzvah.  He has a very creative reading of the verse, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @YEZ I agree - though I was responding to the comment about R' EW. I assume his comments were of similar nature.

Comment: @Zvi Never saw it inside, but the way I have heard it quoted I think he actually meant it as an application of lo sa'amod

Comment: Didn't check it, but VERY impressive sourcing, +1

Comment: Yes, I meant "spiritual danger" along the same lines as the Chafetz Chayim you cited, i.e. danger to the soul from not following the Torah. However, R' Elchanan was talking about something a bit different (and the Chafetz Chayim also mentioned this at the end of the piece): physical danger that can result from spiritual deficiencies. See [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43740/does-learning-torah-or-doing-mitzvos-protect-others-from-harm#comment113680_43740). @YEZ